# Format Date in TextBox

Tags: vb.net

I really need help
I save record in the field `Product_Date` as Type `Text` in my Table access.
Sometimes I save record of date `Product_Date` only the year for example like that (2007) Or (1995) Or ( 2019)...
With my code I tried to make the date when i click DataGridView1 appear in TextBox3 like this: `dd-MM-yyyy`. It works very well but the problem when I get to the line registered with a year only
I'll get this error message:

```
Convertion from string "2007" to type "date" is not valid
```

How to do it to avoid this error message?
My Code :

```
 Private Sub DataGridView1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.Click
    Try
        With DataGridView1.CurrentRow
            TextBox1.Text = .Cells("Product_Id").Value.ToString()
            TextBox2.Text = .Cells("Product_Nom").Value.ToString()
            TextBox3.Text = .Cells("Product_Date").Value.ToString()
            TextBox3.Text = Format(CDate(Convert.ToString(TextBox3.Text)), "dd-MM-yyyy")

        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: My suggestion, re-think your data structure and use a Date/Time format for dates. You want to present the year only, you can do it using the Year part of the Date. If you need just a `Year` reference for some reason, add a field that just stores the Year (a numeric value would do). But, you shouldn't need it. SQL lets you filter the year from  a DateTime field anyway. In any case, if you need to store dates, use the appropriate data type, then present the Date in the preferred UI format.

Comment: Thank you very much Jimi.how can retrieve and save only year in field access : DateTime

Comment: `Dim myDate As Date = New Date(2019, 1, 1) =>`  store the Date. When you read it back, it depends on what you read it from. Assuming that you read the field directly from the DataTable and the Date/Time Field is in `Column(0)`: `Dim myYear As Integer = DirectCast(myTable.Rows(0)(0), Date).Year`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you might want to try is to take this string read from the database and convert it to a `DateTime` object, this way you can format it however you want as a date. To do this with solely a year you can use the `DateTime.ParseExact` method. Here is a small example. I have edited it to include the cases where the string is not just a year. There is probably a nicer way to do this (Try inside of Try isn't the nicest thing to look at) but I will leave that for you to decide.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim Dates() As String = {"2007", "2-29-2008", "5/29/2006"}
    Dim oDate As DateTime

    For i As Integer = 0 To 2

        'Try to parse as formatted date
        Try
            oDate = DateTime.Parse(Dates(i))

        Catch castEx As FormatException
            'Could not format normally, try treating as solely a year
            Try
                oDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Dates(i), "yyyy", Nothing)

            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
                Continue For
            End Try

        End Try
        'Print converted date
        Console.WriteLine(oDate.ToString())
    Next
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Here the `yyyy` specifies that it's reading in only a year value. 
This outputs:

```
01/01/2007 12:00:00 AM
```

But remember that the ToString method of datetime is overloaded, so if you use `oDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")` it will print:

```
01-01-2007
```

I used [this page](http://net-informations.com/q/faq/stringdate.html) as a reference.

Note: This can be done the exact same way with a `Date` object instead of a `DateTime` since they share the same methods.

This is not the optimal way of storing / using dates, when possible you should be using actual date datatypes instead of text in your database. If it's not too late I would suggest rethinking your columns but if that's out of your control at this point it's fine to go for workaround methods like these.

Comment: Thank you Patrick.how to make  this part of code (dim idate as string ="2007" .. in my code.

Comment: When you recieve the value from product_date, it is already a string, so you would want to use that value in the place of the string in my example. You would also only want to do this if the first conversion fails.

Comment: Thank you for help.when i go at home i will tried it.

Comment: Thank you very much Patrick .. perfectly resolved .. very nice of you .. Cordially .. SABRINE